# Ruby - Access multidimensional hash and avoid access nil object

Tags: ruby, hash, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby: Nils in an IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393974/ruby-nils-in-an-if-statement)
>   [Is there a clean way to avoid calling a method on nil in a nested params hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429790/is-there-a-clean-way-to-avoid-calling-a-method-on-nil-in-a-nested-params-hash)

Let's say I try to access a hash like this:

```
my_hash['key1']['key2']['key3']
```

This is nice if key1, key2 and key3 exist in the hash(es), but what if, for example key1 doesn't exist?

Then I would get `NoMethodError: undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`. And nobody likes that.

So far I deal with this doing a conditional like:

`if my_hash['key1'] && my_hash['key1']['key2']` ...

Is this appropriate, is there any other Rubiest way of doing so?

Comment: The accepted answer mentions every possible method except the correct one for Ruby 2.3+ : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

Answer (score 191, accepted):

There are many approaches to this.

If you use Ruby 2.3 or above, you can use [dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig)

```
my_hash.dig('key1', 'key2', 'key3')
```

Plenty of folks stick to plain ruby and chain the `&&` guard tests.

You could use stdlib [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) too:

```
my_hash.fetch('key1', {}).fetch('key2', {}).fetch('key3', nil)
```

Some like chaining ActiveSupport's [#try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method.

```
my_hash.try(:[], 'key1').try(:[], 'key2').try(:[], 'key3')
```

Others use [andand](https://github.com/raganwald/andand)

```
myhash['key1'].andand['key2'].andand['key3']
```

Some people think [egocentric nils](https://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2009-02-02/hopeless_egocentricity.md) are a good idea (though someone might hunt you down and torture you if they found you do this).

```
class NilClass
  def method_missing(*args); nil; end
end

my_hash['key1']['key2']['key3']
```

You could use [Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (or alias inject).

```
['key1','key2','key3'].reduce(my_hash) {|m,k| m && m[k] }
```

Or perhaps extend Hash or just your target hash object with a nested lookup method

```
module NestedHashLookup
  def nest *keys
    keys.reduce(self) {|m,k| m && m[k] }
  end
end

my_hash.extend(NestedHashLookup)
my_hash.nest 'key1', 'key2', 'key3'
```

Oh, and how could we forget the [maybe](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/10/10/the-maybe-monad-in-ruby/) monad?

```
Maybe.new(my_hash)['key1']['key2']['key3']
```

Comment: You can also try the monadic gem, which has a Maybe (and other monads) which help with handling exceptions

Comment: What are your thoughts on using `rescue nil` at the end of the statement?

Comment: @jakeonrails `rescue nil` is almost always evil. 1) it can capture and silently discard an exception you weren't aware could be thrown; 2) exceptions are computationally expensive flow control -- one should only use them for exceptional behavior, not expected behavior.

Comment: You can use `dig` method for hash after Ruby 2.3, http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

Comment: Or https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+keypath

Comment: You can use dig method for hash *and Array* since Ruby 2.3

Comment: `my_hash.dig` will fail if `my_hash` is `nil`. Consider using the safe navigation operator instead or combined with `.dig` as: `my_hash&.dig(:key1, :key2, :key3)` or `my_hash&.key1&.key2&.key3`.

Comment: The syntax of the safe navigator operator on hashes in my previous comment is incorrect. The correct syntax is: `my_hash&.[]('key1')&.[]('key2')&.[]('key3')`.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use [Object#andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/).

```
my_hash['key1'].andand['key2'].andand['key3']
```

Answer (score 5):

Conditions `my_hash['key1'] && my_hash['key1']['key2']` don't feel [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Alternatives:

1) [autovivification](http://t-a-w.blogspot.com/2006/07/autovivification-in-ruby.html) magic. From that post:

```
def autovivifying_hash
   Hash.new {|ht,k| ht[k] = autovivifying_hash}
end
```

Then, with your example:

```
my_hash = autovivifying_hash     
my_hash['key1']['key2']['key3']
```

It's similar to the Hash.fetch approach in that both operate with new hashes as default values, but this moves details to the creation time.
Admittedly, this is a bit of cheating: it will never return 'nil' just an empty hash, which is created on the fly. Depending on your use case, this could be wasteful.

2) Abstract away the data structure with its lookup mechanism, and handle the non-found case behind the scenes. A simplistic example:

```
def lookup(model, key, *rest) 
    v = model[key]
    if rest.empty?
       v
    else
       v && lookup(v, *rest)
    end
end
#####

lookup(my_hash, 'key1', 'key2', 'key3')
=> nil or value
```

3) If you feel monadic you can take a look at this,  [Maybe](http://meta-meta.blogspot.com/2006/12/monads-in-ruby-part-2-maybe-then-again.html)