# Check hash for nil values

Tags: ruby, hash, null

I'm trying to analyze tweets off of Twitter and one of the things I would like to include is the location. Unfortunately, some of the values are nil and I keep getting the error

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I would like to just run a check to see if the value is nil or not but I can't get anything to work.

The input would look like this if it is nil

```
tweet = {"metadata"=> {"geo"=>nil}}
```

and this if it has value

```
tweet = {"metadata"=> {"geo"=>{"coordinates"=>[0,1]}}
```

This is what I've tried

```
if "#{tweet['metadata']['geo']}".nil? == true
  puts("nil")
else
  puts("#{tweet['metadata']['geo']['coordinates']}"
end
```

What I've noticed is that it just checks to see if geo is empty because it outputs "nil" if I change the if statement to equal false. I'm not sure how else to check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem may be that you're interpolating the hash in the string, which is converting the nil into an empty string, which is not actually nil.

Try:

```
if tweet['metadata']['geo'].nil?
  puts("nil")
else
  puts("#{tweet['metadata']['geo']['coordinates']}")
end
```

Comment: Well that does it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Using fetch on hash is a better way to Handle this type of problems.
The below link to another answer shows how elegantly and beautifully this is handled.
[Ruby - Access multidimensional hash and avoid access nil object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130726/ruby-access-multidimensional-hash-and-avoid-access-nil-object)

Answer (score 2):

Use `present?` which checks for `nil` and `blank` as well. Check with following code.

```
if tweet['metadata']['geo'].present?
  puts("nil")
else
  puts("#{tweet['metadata']['geo']['coordinates']}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, nowadays I'd suggest using `dig` with safely returns nil if keys are not present.

```
tweet = { "metadata" => { "geo"=> { "coordinates" => [0, 1] } } }
tweet.dig("metadata", "geo", "coordinates")
=> [0, 1]

missing_tweet = { "metadata" => { "geo" => nil } }
missing_tweet.dig("metadata", "geo", "coordinates")
=> nil
```