# Safe navigation equivalent to Rails try for hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, you can do `hash.try(:[], :key)` which helps if `hash` is potentially `nil`.
Is there an equivalent version for using the new Ruby 2.3 safe navigation operator `&.` with `[]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby - Access multidimensional hash and avoid access nil object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130726/ruby-access-multidimensional-hash-and-avoid-access-nil-object)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

`&.` is not equivalent to Rails' `try`, but you can use `&.` for hashes. Just use it, nothing special.

```
hash[:key1]&.[](:key2)&.[](:key3)
```

Although I would not do that.

Comment: Good point with `&.` and `try` being different. I was only thinking in the case of `hash` being `nil`.
What I ended up using was `hash&.[](:key)`

Comment: @bbozo Yes. `&.` was introduced in Ruby 2.3.

Comment: `hash&.dig(:key1, :key2, :key3)` looks nicer :)

Comment: In which way they are not equivalent and why would you not do that?

Comment: This no longer appears to work as of ruby 3.3 (and probably earlier but I'm not able to test for which version it stopped working in right now). I'd recommend the `&.dig(...)` approach instead.

Answer (score 95):

## Ruby 2.3 and later

There's `Hash#dig` method now that does just that:

> Retrieves the value object corresponding to the each key objects repeatedly.

```
h = { foo: {bar: {baz: 1}}}

h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)           #=> 1
h.dig(:foo, :zot)                 #=> nil
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

## Pre Ruby 2.3

I usually had something like this put into my intializer:

```
Class Hash
    def deep_fetch *args
      x = self
      args.each do |arg|
        x = x[arg]
        return nil if x.nil?
      end
      x
    end
end
```

and then

```
response.deep_fetch 'PaReqCreationResponse', 'ThreeDSecureVERes', 'Message', 'VERes', 'CH', 'enrolled'
```

in one wacky case.

The general consensus in the community seems to be to avoid both try and the lonely operator `&.`

Comment: Looks suspiciously similar in use cases to `dig`, introduced in 2.3 just as `&.`. Any differences?

Comment: It is better to place your extensions to `Hash` in a module and `prepend` it instead of doing a direct monkeypatch.

Comment: @DavidS. can you elaborate?

Comment: Placing your extensions in a module allows you to test them in isolation from the actual class you're patching, and then actually patching it via `Module#prepend` will give you the ability to invoke `super` from your monkeypatch to call the method that you are overriding.

Comment: @DavidS. ah yes, I agree in principle, but in this case there's no change to existing behavior, it's not the use case prepend was created for (think alias_method_chain). Also, prepend only exists since Ruby 2.0 and the first example is there to provide a solution for earlier ruby versions.

Comment: but `h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz, :bing)` will raise an error

Comment: @JohnBachir you write this as you'd expect `dig` to swallow the fact that `1` is not `nil` or a hash. I say, the current behavior of `dig` is exactly what I expect. (And `1&.[](:bing)` will not work either).

Answer (score 17):

While `hash&.[](:key)` is elegant to the trained rubyist, I'd just use `hash && hash[:key]` as it reads better and more intuitively for the programmer coming after me, who may not be as familiar with the intricacies of ruby. Some extra characters in the codebase can sometimes save a whole lot of googling for someone else.

(Given the context you want to use this in is in a conditional statement, of course.)

Comment: ...especially as this syntax (`&.[](:key)`) is anything but well searchable!

`dig` on the other hand can be identified as a method by the way it is used; and it's therefore relatively easy to get further infos on it by searching _ruby method dig_, e.g.

Answer (score 14):

A rather more legible way to use the safe navigation operator than using `hash&.[](:slug)` is to use the `fetch` method:

```
hash&.fetch(:slug)
```

If your key may not be defined, you can use the second argument as a default:

```
hash&.fetch(:slug, nil)
```

Comment: This may be appropriate in some scenarios, but it's worth nothing that #[] and #fetch are not the same method, and fetch will throw an exception if the key does not exist in the hash.

Comment: @ZoFreX: That's why I included `fetch(…, nil)` in the answer, which is exactly the same as `#[]`.

Answer (score 12):

Accepted answer will not account for when `hash` is nil...

You can rewrite what you have using the safe nav operator before the `.try` and that will work

`hash&.try(:[], :key)`

but you can also use:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

A way you could do this on a hash is by doing...

```
hash&.dig(:key1, :key2 ...)
```

which will return nil if any key fetch isn't present.

```
{ key1: { key2: 'info' } }
```

would return 'info'

```
{ key1: { wrong_key: 'info' } }
```

would return `nil`

Comment: This is the way to do it cleanly. `hash&.dig( :key1 )`. Thank you.