# Find out if a sub-key exists in a key

Tags: ruby, hashtable, yaml

I have a YAML file like this:

```
options:
    some_option: 'foo'
```

which I load as a hash `yaml`, on which I want to be able to use `include?` to get a boolean telling whether a key exists in it or not.

To get the sub-keys of `options`, I would normally use `yaml["options"]["some_option"]`, however how would I find out if the YAML hash includes `["options"]["some_option"]`? You can't do something like:

```
if yaml.include? "options"["some_option"] # or
if yaml.include? ["options"]["some_option"] # or even
if yaml.include? yaml["options"]["some_option"]
```

Is there a way to retrieve the sub-key of `options` in the YAML hash?

Comment: You mean without loading the whole Yaml file?

Comment: Why can't you use `has_key?` or something?

Comment: I think yaml is irrelevant. The question is misleading. It is simply about nested hashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Nils in an IF statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393974/ruby-nils-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the expected values in the yaml file, you can just use Ruby's typecasting:

```
if yaml["options"] && yaml["options"]["some_option"]
```

If `yaml["options"]` doesn't exist, it will return `nil`, which will short circuit the `if` statement and return `false`.

Obviously, this won't work as an existence check if a valid value for "some_option" is falsey. You'll need to explicitly use `has_key?`:

```
if yaml.has_key?("options") && yaml["options"].has_key?("some_option")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yaml["options"].include? "some_option"
```

And if it's possible for `"options"` to not be set:

```
(yaml["options"] || {}).include? "some_option"
```